# SWT: How to detect when a new CTabItem is added to CTabFolder?

Tags: java, swt, ctabitem

I am adding CTabItems dynamically, but when I add a new CTabItem and call setSelection on CTabFolder, it doesn't call selectionListener of CTabFolder. Is there any other way to detect when a new CTabItem is added to CTabFolder.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You can force a selection event to be sent when you do the `setSelection` by using the tab control's `notifyListeners` method:

```
Event event = new Event();
event.item = theTabItem;
tabFolder.notifyListeners(SWT.Selection, event);
```